# Invalid Activity context in window interactive check, assuming interactive

Tags: android, ads, facebook-audience-network

When Facebook Android ad banner is shown, this message is written to Logcat every 1 second:

> Invalid Activity context in window interactive check, assuming
>   interactive.

(facebook Android sdk is 4.19.0).

What does this message mean?